# How to transcribe audio without using external APIs?

Tags: macos, command-line, srt, transcription

I would prefer not to use Amazon, Google etc, so how would I use my own computer (macOS) to get a time-stamped transcription of mp3s and videos? Preferably on the command line. So I could do something like this

```
transcribe -o oliver_twist.srt oliver_twist.mp3
```

.. to create a SRT subtitle file from an mp3.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux there's a package called voice2json: http://voice2json.org/commands.html#transcribe-wav

simply if you have an audio file: `sample.wav` you run

`voice2json transcribe-wav < simple.wav`

and you get the output

`{"text": "sample voice recording", "transcribe_seconds": 0.123, "wav_seconds": 1.23}`

I believe you can install this Linux package to macOS. To do that just look at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53096/is-it-possible-to-install-linux-packages-on-os-x

EDIT:

To get the srt, you need a package called `jq`. You can install it the same way. Let's say your output from previous command is output.json. What you need to do is:

`jq .text output.json > subtitles.srt` and the output will be saved as `subtitles.srt`

Comment: by the way if you need help turning the output into .srt just comment here

Comment: yes, how to get .srt .. or just plain text?

Comment: I added to the answer. If it works can you upvote or accept as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

*Kdenlive* is able to generate SRT files from an audio file: see [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org). It is also available for MacOs.

Once Kdenlive is installed, you can install *Kdenlive command line* tools to operate Kdenlive from the command line: see [Kdenlive command line](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=122193#p316287).

Comment: Doesn't appear to way to install a recent version on macOS. The command line tools are 7 years old, and the documentation seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Sorry about that.